# how to check customer logged in or not in cms block page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, cms, header

i have cms custom header page i want to check

when  click on (custom header)
it will check customer logged in or not

i already try this

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
}
```

> those  codes are showing in  headers

any one have idea???

Comment: You can't add php code in cms page @prabhakaran7

Comment: can i create new module

Comment: or what i do.............

Comment: If you have theme then you can try below method. See the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a helper class ( as described below) and call your helper class function in the template file to check a customer is logged in or not

I assume you are using a custom module name Company_MyModule and create the helper class under that custom module

step 1: Create the Helper Class

Helper Class: **Data.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\MyModule\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        return (bool)$this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
    }
}
```

**step 2:**
Using helper class to check a customer is logged in or not in the template file.

```
<?php
$_helpercustomerlogin = $this->helper('\Company\MyModule\Helper\Data');
if($_helpercustomerlogin->isLoggedIn()){
      // code for logged in customer
    } else {
      // code for not logged in customer 
    }
?>
```